# Как вызвать событие - нажатие кнопки мыши?

Tags: java, delphi, eclipse, visual-studio

Как сделать, чтобы курсор мыши самостоятельно производил щелчок? И также мне надо, чтобы была возможность щелкать вне формы приложения.

Comment: > eclipse delphi java visual-studio

Вы все же определитесь для начала, на каком языке.

Comment: @Nofate более интересует delphi и visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

на с++ через windows.h что-нить типа такого (QT, хотя не думаю, что на java будет сильно отличаться)

```
//кликаем
    void Simulation::click()
    {
        INPUT *buffer = new INPUT[1];
        buffer->type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        buffer->mi.dx = 0;
        buffer->mi.dy = 0;
        buffer->mi.mouseData = 0;
        buffer->mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
        buffer->mi.time = 0;
        buffer->mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;
        SendInput(1,buffer,sizeof(INPUT));
        delete buffer;
    }
```

Comment: @majatu, т. е. надо сделать 

    #include windows.h.
А можете объяснить, что такое тип INPUT и что такое mi, SendInput?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: я делал #include <qt_windows.h>

Comment: тут скорее дело не в языке, а в платформе, на которой ты делаешь клик, т.к. это системная функция

Answer (score 1):

Используй стандартны класс Robot в java там можно передвигать нажимать на мышку а также на клавиатуру в и вне программы как будто перед компом сидит виртуальный человек.

Answer (score 0):

чтобы курсор мыши самостоятельно производил щелчок*

в delphi есть метод события мыши Mouse_Event

попробуй поэкспериментировать, меняя параметры, следующий код

```
var
  pnt: TPoint;
...
begin
  pnt.X:= random(1024);
  pnt.Y:= random(768);
  SetCursorPos(pnt.X, pnt.Y);
  Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, pnt.x, pnt.y, 0, 0);
...
```